# why record is not present after first scenario cucumber test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Hi i am working on rails project where I have to test the API with Cucumber. i am creating a record in my first scenario and in my second scenario i am verifying that record but as my second scenario executed the previously created record does not present in the db.

Feature file:

```
Feature: Bill Reminder

  Scenario: Validate POST bill_reminder API with valid parameters
    When I make POST bill_reminder API call
    Then It should return success for bill_reminder

  Scenario: Validate GET bill_reminder API with valid login token
    when I send a GET request to bill reminder details
    Then the json response should have title bill reminder
```

Steps File:

```
When(/^I make POST bill_reminder API call$/) do
  @url = 'http://example.com/api/bill_reminders'
  @params = {
              data: {
                type: "bill-reminders",
                attributes: {
                  title: "bill reminder",
                  all_day: "0",
                  start_date: "1409175049",
                  end_date: "1409175049"
                }
              }
            }
  @login_token = 'nev4hPOqyVCXGnOXLYPUhQ'
  @user_id = 402
end

Then(/^It should return success for bill_reminder$/) do
  header 'login_token', @login_token
  header 'user-id', @user_id
  response = post @url, @params

  response_body = JSON response.body
  @id = response_body['data']['id']
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)
end

When(/^I send a GET request to bill reminder details$/) do
  @url = "http://example.com/api/bill_reminders/#{@id}"
  @user_id = 402
  @login_token = 'nev4hPOqyVCXGnOXLYPUhQ'
end

Then(/^the json response should have title bill reminder$/) do
  header 'login_token', @login_token
  header 'user-id', @user_id

  response = get @url
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)
end
```

Here when i debug my second scenario "I send a GET request to bill reminder details" the record created in the first scenario is not present. Please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not used to test with cucumber, but I guess each test runs like a transaction. Each one creates and deletes the data for that respective test.

Comment: any idea how i will verify the created record?

Comment: Try with something like `expect {response = post(@url,@params) }.to change(Post, :count).by(1)`

Comment: Thanks but i need to verify the second api as well with GET method

Comment: then you first create the post by code (`Post.create.....`) and then do the get request